# How can I extends Message of Spring Integration?

Tags: spring-integration

I want to extends spring integration message.
I want to add some header value during the time message flows through channels.

I read the documentation of MessageHeader like the followings. How can I get some sample of third cases?

> One way to create message headers is to use the MessageBuilder:
>
> MessageBuilder.withPayload("foo").setHeader("key1",
>   "value1").setHeader("key2", "value2");

A second option is to create

> org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage passing a payload
>   as Object and headers as a java.util.Map:   Map headers = new
>   HashMap();  headers.put("key1", "value1");  headers.put("key2",
>   "value2");  new GenericMessage("foo", headers);

A third option is to

> use org.springframework.messaging.support.MessageHeaderAccessor or one
>   of its subclasses to create specific categories of headers.

Answer (score 1):

If the requirement is only to add some header value during the time message flows through channels then header enricher can serve the purpose.

```
<int:header-enricher input-channel="in" output-channel="out">
     <int:header name="foo" value="123"/>
     <int:header name="bar" ref="someBean"/>
</int:header-enricher>
```